# Extracting the values assigned to NOT x from a given string?

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that I can use to extract out the values assigned to variable x in the following string:

```
(req.idf=6ca9a AND (req.ster=201 OR req.ster=st_home) AND (req.ste=hi OR req.ster=hijst_iuer OR ((req.ster=laHome OR req.ster=laHome_Jtre) AND (tax=IN OR taxIP=MX))) AND NOT ((x=u259 AND (x=66438 OR x=5423)) OR x=9853))AND(NOT x=28743)
```

I am trying to get the output in the following format, by getting the numerical values assigned to the variable followed by NOT x: 66438, 5423, 9853, 28743

So far, I have tried creating regex like: `(?:(?:NOT\s*x=)|(?:NOTx=))(\d+)`, which can only fetch the value for 28743. [It fetches the numerical values assigned to the "NOT x=" or "NOTx=" string before the "x="]

How can I modify the regex to also include the instances where I can retrieve the numerical values assigned to x, where NOT is followed by parenthesis, and within the opening "(" and ")" and there are multiple assignments to the variable "x" inside the parenthesis.
Some examples: "x= 3424 AND NOT (x=34343 OR x=1214 OR x=11121 AND (x=23232 OR x=1121))"
In this case, the regex should retrieve the values : [34343, 1214, 11121, 23232, 1121]

Comment: You can shorten your current regex to `NOT\s*x=(\d+)` What tool or language are you using? What if there is another value other than `x=` in between, like `NOT (x=34343 OR x=1214 OR y=11121 AND (x=23232 OR x=1121))` Should you take balanced parenthesis into account?

Comment: I am using Python, no there won't be another value other than x= in between.
The parenthesis will always be balanced.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to do it in two steps, because the `NOT` can be before
a `x = number` or before a full parenthesis group. So I would look for
`NOT` one of them in a first step, then if you match a parenthesis group then
look for occurrences of `x = number` inside it.

But, just to note, **I think this is quite dangerous**, because if
you have a `NOT` again inside this group, then it will invert your
condition as `NOT (v = 495 AND NOT x = 84)` is equivalent to
`NOT v = 495 OR x = 84`
([because of boolean algebra](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/boolean/bool_6.html)). To be safer, you may need to use an
expression parser and simplifier, so that you can list all the values that
`x` should have or not have.

But if you forget this problematic, and you know what your input should be
like, then try this PHP solution:

```php
<?php

// Test and see the explanation of the regex pattern: https://regex101.com/r/k94a0A/2
define('REGEX_PATTERN', '/NOT
(?: # Two options:
  # A) x = 1234, prefixed with at least a whitespace char.
  \s+x\s*=\s*(?<x_value>\d+)
  | # or
  # B) a balanced parenthesis group. 
  \s* # Optional whitespace chars.
  (?<balanced_parenthesis>
    \( # Opening parenthesis.
    (?:
      [^()]* # Any chars which aren\'t parenthesis.
      | # Or
      \g<balanced_parenthesis> # Recursion: a child balanced parenthesis group.
    )*
    \) # Closing parenthesis.
  )
)/x');

$input = '(
  req.idf = 6ca9a 
  AND (
    req.ster = 201 
    OR req.ster = st_home
  ) 
  AND (
    req.ste = hi 
    OR req.ster = hijst_iuer 
    OR (
      (
        req.ster = laHome 
        OR req.ster = laHome_Jtre
      ) 
      AND (
        tax = IN 
        OR taxIP = MX
      )
    )
  ) 
  AND NOT (
    (
      x = u259 
      AND (
        x = 66438 
        OR x = 5423
      )
    ) 
    OR x = 9853
  )
) 
AND (NOT x = 28743)';

$x_values = [];

if (preg_match_all(REGEX_PATTERN, $input, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        // If we found "NOT x = number", then store this number.
        if (!empty($match['x_value'])) {
            $x_values[] = $match['x_value'];
        }
        // If we found a balanced parenthesis after a NOT then look inside it.
        if (!empty($match['balanced_parenthesis'])) {
            // Look for "x = number" occurences.
            if (preg_match_all('/\bx\s*=\s*(?<x_value>\d+)/', $match['balanced_parenthesis'], $x_matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
                foreach ($x_matches as $x_match) {
                    $x_values[] = $x_match['x_value'];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

var_export($x_values);
```

It outputs:

```php
array (
  0 => '66438',
  1 => '5423',
  2 => '9853',
  3 => '28743',
)
```

You can run the PHP code online here: https://onlinephp.io/c/6cb61

Also notice that this solution isn't recursive, but it could be
improved. Effectively, you could have
`NOT(v = 8 AND NOT(x = 4 OR x = 5))`. If you put my code into a
function, you could call it again if you match a parenthesis group.
You could add a parameter to "negate" or not, so that you can
put all `x` values in two arrays, one for the number to include and
one for the numbers to not include. But this becomes slowly complex
and brings you back to a possible use of an expression parser.

The regex pattern is explained and testable here: https://regex101.com/r/k94a0A/2

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, As I only can use Python, I am trying to change the flavour to Python, here - https://regex101.com/r/k94a0A/2, but it's giving me error.

Comment: @Moh What a pitty, I effectively see that [Python doesn't handle recursion or balanced groups out of the box](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrecurse.html). But it seems that you should be able to get it working with an alternative regex module. Perhaps [pypi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/)